# JQuery: add index to each element as data to 'this'

Tags: jquery

I am making this simple code that iterates through *select* to convert it into a list, for instance:

```
<select>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
</select>
```

will become:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

The problem surges when there are two *select* the lists become the combination of the two, (see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lq83596/1/))

This is the code that I am using:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.showLikeList = function () {
        $('<ul class="show-like-list-box"></ul>').insertAfter($(this));
        $(this).children().each(function () {
            $("ul.show-like-list-box").append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
        });
        return this;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: your fiddle link is not working..

Comment: Here is the working link: http://jsfiddle.net/5Lq83596/

Comment: oops, fixed it... thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's your plugin with 2 minor concept changes.

Added an `each` loop for all elements in selector collection.

Created instance variable of `<ul>` element being added instead of using the class selector which will locate all instances

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.showLikeList = function () {
        /* should add a check to see if stylesheet already added */
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="files/css/show-like-list.css" type="text/css" />');

        return this.each(function (i,el) {
            $(el).addClass('show-like-list-old-element');
             /* create instance of list to add to DOM */
            var $list = $('<ul class="show-like-list-box"></ul>').insertAfter($(this));
            $(el).children().each(function (idx) { /* <== here's your <option> index*/
                /* append to list instance */           
                $list.append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
            });
        });
    };

}(jQuery));
```

If you want to get the index of the options you can get it from the first argument of `each` . I forgot to add it to demo

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7w2ksg4p/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: I would also add a check to see if the `<link>` tag exists before appending another one. Give it an ID and check for that element....in case you end up calling plugin more than once in page